# AWS Cognito: How to prevent collection of phone number?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a React app with AWS Amplify integration. When adding auth via Cognito, I do not want to collect phone numbers when signing up people, but I cannot change the settings of the user pool (since it has been created automatically in the `amplify add auth` process.

How can I prevent phone number collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
amplify add auth
```

Next, in your generated -cloudformation-template.yml in the directory amplify/backend/auth// make sure that you have the following:

```
Schema:
  - Name: phone_number
    Required: false
```

This will make the phone_number optional.